# Dropdown menu not working after placing another div

Tags: html, css

Before i placed the div class "hero", the dropdown menu works well but after i placed the div class "hero", the dropdown menu did not work anymore. please help me I am new to html and css. thank you.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.here {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.menu .here .choice {
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline;
  border: 3px;
  background-color: orange;
  opacity: .8;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.here .heh {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

.here .heh:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

.subs {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: orange;
  display: none;
  color: white;
}

.subs:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

.choice:hover .subs {
  display: block;
}

.hero {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.hero .head1 {
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 270px;
  font-family: bodoni;
}

.hero .head3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: helvetica;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="one.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="two.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul class="here">
      <li class="choice"><a href="" class="heh">About</a>
        <ul class="here">
          <li><a href="" class="subs">You</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com" class="subs">Me</a> </li>
          <li><a href="" class="subs">Us</a></li>

        </ul>

      </li>
      <li class="choice"><a href="" class="heh">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li class="choice"><a href="" class="heh">Sign Up</a></li>
      <li class="choice"><a href="" class="heh">Log in</a></li>

    </ul>


  </div>

  <div class="hero">
    <h1 class="head1">something.com</h1>
    <h3 class="head3">this is a random sentence.</h3>

  </div>

</body>
```

These code works whenever I eliminate the second div which is the "hero" class. But I don't know what happened here. I need your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.hero` element is on top of your menu. You can check it by using the dev tools of your browser and hovering over the element. You will see, that it expands over the menu and covers it, even though you can see it visually. You can add something like this:

```
.hero {
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

That way you can access elements beneath `.hero`.
Another solution is to add a negative z-index to the element, which stacks it behind the menu and makes it accessible again

Answer (score 0):

You can add `position:relative` div above `absolute` div and need to change some menu css

```css
body{
margin: 0;
}

.here,.hereinner{
list-style-type: none;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;

}



.menu .here .choice{
float: right;
display: inline;
border: 3px;
background-color: orange;
opacity: .8;
line-height: 40px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 20px;

}

.hereinner li{
background-color: orange;
opacity: 1;
line-height: 40px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 20px;

}

.here .heh,.subs{
  width: 200px;
height: 40px;
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
display: block;
}

.here .heh:hover{
background-color: green;
}

.hereinner{
display: none;
}

.subs{
text-decoration: none;
background-color: orange;
color: white;
}

.subs:hover{
background-color: green;
}

.choice:hover .hereinner{
display: block;
}
.clearfix{
  clear:both;
}
.posrel{
  position:relative;
}

.hero{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
margin-left: 0;
margin-top: 0;
}

.hero .head1{
color: black;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 70px;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 270px;
font-family: bodoni;
}

.hero .head3{
text-align: center;
font-family: helvetica;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
<ul class="here">
        <li class="choice" ><a href="" class="heh">About</a>
            <ul class="hereinner">
                <li ><a href="" class="subs">You</a></li>
                <li ><a href="http://www.facebook.com" class="subs">Me</a> </li>
                <li><a href=""  class="subs">Us</a></li>

            </ul>

        </li>
        <li class="choice"><a href="" class="heh">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li class="choice"><a href="" class="heh">Sign Up</a></li>
        <li class="choice"><a href="" class="heh">Log in</a></li>

    </ul>
    <div class="clearfix">
    
    </div>


</div>
<div class="posrel">
    <div class="hero">
        <h1 class="head1">something.com</h1>
        <h3 class="head3">this is a random sentence.</h3>

</div>          

</div>
```